# Erasing the last element with the reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, std, reverse-iterator

Recently I found the following in the code I'm maintaining:

```
for (reverse_iterator rit = base_container::rbegin(); rit != base_container::rend() && 0 < N; N--) 
{
  another_container->push_back(*rit);
  base_container::erase((++rit).base());
}
```

It tries to remove the last element from a container (std::list in this case) in a loop using the reverse_iterator. The point is that it looks like it should work properly, but it doesn't (some memory corruptions occur due to invalid iterators) and I wonder why? Is there any restriction or rule to not do so?

Thanks.

P.S. To prevent any improvements for the solution, I've already re-written it to make it work. The question is why the code above is not working properly?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why so complicated? Can't you first reverse copy the whole container and then clear the original one? Also, what is base_container?

Comment: std::list as I wrote above

Comment: Do you inherit from container as `base_container::` suggests ? :-(

Comment: The base_container is just a typedef for std:list<your_type>

Comment: @Rom098: Sorry my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All iterators after calling `erase` are invalidated. However, `erase` returns an iterator that you can use.

Comment: Not all iterators. But certainly the iterator pointing at the erased element.

Answer (score 1):

`rit` is *invalidated* by the `erase` call.

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the return value of `erase()` and convert it back to `reverse_iterator` to avoid iterator invalidation.

```
for (reverse_iterator rit = base_container::rbegin(); rit != base_container::rend() && 0 < N; N--) 
{
  another_container->push_back(*rit);
  auto it =base_container::erase((++rit).base()); //erase will return an iteraotor
  rit(it);//converting iterator to reverse_iterator.
}
```